# How do you combine more than one pathlib object?

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

I've got two Path objects using Python's pathlib library, `pathA = Path('/source/parent')` and `pathB = Path('/child/grandchild')`. What's the most direct way to combine the two so that you get a `Path('/source/parent/child/grandchild')` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath):

You can do this easy by `pathlib.PurePath(*pathsegments)`

> "Each element of pathsegments can be either a string representing a
> path segment, an object implementing the os.PathLike interface which
> returns a string, or another path object."

```
>>> PurePath('foo', 'some/path', 'bar')
PurePosixPath('foo/some/path/bar')
>>> PurePath(Path('foo'), Path('bar'))
PurePosixPath('foo/bar')
```

So for you it would be:

```
pathA = pathlib.Path('source/parent')
pathB = pathlib.Path('child/grandchild')
pathAB = pathlib.PurePath(pathA, pathB)
```

```
Output: source/parent/child/grandchild
```

**Note**

> "When several absolute paths are given, the last is taken as an anchor
> (mimicking os.path.join()’s behaviour):"

```
>>> PurePath('/etc', '/usr', 'lib64')
PurePosixPath('/usr/lib64')
>>> PureWindowsPath('c:/Windows', 'd:bar')
PureWindowsPath('d:bar')
```

Even when you do this:

```
pathA = pathlib.Path('/source/parent')
pathB = pathlib.Path('/child/grandchild')
pathAB = pathlib.PurePath(pathA, pathB)
```

Pathlib will handle pathB like a path object that is represented by a string.

```
Output: source/child/grandchild
```

Comment: Okay I've got why it wasn't working for me. So the correct format for using the doc's way of combining paths don't allow the `'/'` used in the start of `pathB`. What that means is that `Path(Path('foo'), Path('bar'))` would work, but not `Path(Path('foo'), Path('/bar'))`

Comment: In fact, `Path(Path('foo'), Path('/bar'))` returns just `Path('/bar')`

Comment: It says "When several absolute paths are given, the last is taken as an anchor (mimicking os.path.join()’s behaviour):"

Answer (score 1):

```
pathA = Path('/source/parent')
pathB = Path('child/grandchild') * remove the first front slash
print(pathA / pathB)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using python 3.11.3 on Win 11.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path, PurePath
>>> patha = Path("C:/bob/zaa/mountain/Exports")
>>> fpath = PurePath(patha,Path("files/bobsfile.jpg"))
>>> fpath
PureWindowsPath('C:/bob/zaa/mountain/Exports/files/bobsfile.jpg')
>>> print(fpath)
C:\bob\zaa\mountain\Exports\files\bobsfile.jpg
```

Ok...got it. cannot have a leading slash in the second argument it appears.

Comment: Hi gopher55, thank you for your time and contribution. Please enhance your answer by explicitly stating the conditions under which your solution works.

Comment: The above should serve to illustrate how to extend an existing Path object. The Path function takes string arguments, but you cannot add a string to an existing Path object. What to do? Use the PurePath function. It only takes Path objects as arguments. so if you only have a string, just enclose it in a second Path argument to PurePath and use the original Path object as first argument. Now you have your longer path.

Answer (score 0):

In Python's `pathlib` library, you can use the `/` operator to concatenate paths. To combine the two paths `patha` and `pathb`, you can simply use the `/` operator as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path

patha = Path('/source/parent')
pathb = Path('/child/grandchild')

combined_path = patha / pathb
```

After performing the concatenation, the `combined_path` variable will hold the resulting path object `Path('/source/parent/child/grandchild')`.

Comment: Hi podrick, thank you for your time and contribution. However, it's better to test your solution before publishing. Your solution gives `/child/grandchild` because the second path is absolute.

Comment: How is the 2nd path obsolete? The OP never said anything about the 2nd path being obsolete. Is this only a condition of your environment?

Comment: Please run the code you wrote yourself and observe the result. Your solution produces `/child/grandchild` instead of the `/source/parent/child/grandchild` you claimed.